# Oracle SQL XOR condition with > 14 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question on sql desgin.

Context:
I have a table called t_master and 13 other tables (lets call them a,b,c... for simplicity)  where it needs to compared.

Logic:

- t_master will be compared to table 'a' where t_master.gen_val =
  a.value.
- If record exist in t_master, retrieve t_master record, else retrieve 'a' record.
- I do not need to retrieve the records if it exists in both tables (t_master and a) - XOR condition
- Repeat this comparison with the remaining 12 tables.

I have some idea on doing this, using WITH to subquery the non-master tables (a,b,c...) first with their respective WHERE clause.
Then use XOR statement to retrieve the records.

Something like

```
WITH a AS (SELECT ...),
b AS (SELECT ...) 

SELECT field1,field2...
FROM t_master FULL OUTER JOIN a FULL OUTER JOIN b FULL OUTER JOIN c...
ON t_master.gen_value = a.value
WHERE ((field1 = x OR field2 = y ) AND NOT (field1 = x AND field2 = y)) 
AND ....
.
.
.
.
```

Seeing that I have 13 tables that I need to full outer join, is there a better way/design to handle this? 
Otherwise I would have at least 2*13 lines of WHERE clause which I'm not sure if that will have impact on the performance as t_master is sort of a log table.

**Assume I cant change any schema.
Currently I'm not sure if this SQL will working correctly yet, so I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction regarding this.

**update from used_by_already's suggestion:**

This is what I'm trying to do (comparison between 2 tables first, before I add more, but I am unable to get values from `ATP_R.TBL_HI_HDR HI_HDR` as it is in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery.
How do i overcome this?

```
SELECT LOG_REPO.UNIQ_ID,
  LOG_REPO.REQUEST_PAYLOAD,
  LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL,
  LOG_REPO.CREATED_BY,
  TO_CHAR(LOG_REPO.CREATED_DT,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS CREATED_DT,
  HI_HDR.HI_NO R_VALUE,
  HI_HDR.CREATED_BY R_CREATED_BY,
  TO_CHAR(HI_HDR.CREATED_DT,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS R_CREATED_DT
FROM ATP_COMMON.VW_CMN_LOG_GEN_REPO LOG_REPO JOIN ATP_R.TBL_HI_HDR HI_HDR ON LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL = HI_HDR.HI_NO
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT NULL
  FROM ATP_R.TBL_HI_HDR HI_HDR
  WHERE LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL = HI_HDR.HI_NO
  )

UNION ALL

SELECT LOG_REPO.UNIQ_ID,
  LOG_REPO.REQUEST_PAYLOAD,
  LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL,
  LOG_REPO.CREATED_BY,
  TO_CHAR(LOG_REPO.CREATED_DT,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS CREATED_DT,
  HI_HDR.HI_NO R_VALUE,
  HI_HDR.CREATED_BY R_CREATED_BY,
  TO_CHAR(HI_HDR.CREATED_DT,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS R_CREATED_DT
FROM ATP_R.TBL_HI_HDR HI_HDR JOIN ATP_COMMON.VW_CMN_LOG_GEN_REPO LOG_REPO ON HI_HDR.HI_NO = LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT NULL
  FROM ATP_COMMON.VW_CMN_LOG_GEN_REPO LOG_REPO
  WHERE HI_HDR.HI_NO = LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL
  )
```

Comment: Though I'm not fully understanding your setup, I can imagine, that what you want can alternatively be realized using `UNION ALL`s of queries using `EXISTS`. Maybe that performs better, provided that there are sufficient indexes on the columns used in the `EXISTS` subqueries.

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: You CANNNOT select columns from tables inside a [NOT] EXISTS subquery, you MUST join that/those tables instead.

Comment: Using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: I have to add this line?    `JOIN ATP_COMMON.VW_CMN_LOG_GEN_REPO LOG_REPO ON HI_HDR.HI_NO = LOG_REPO.GEN_VAL`

Answer (score 0):

Full outer joins used to exclude all matching rows can be an expensive query. You don't supply much detail, but *perhaps* using NOT EXISTS would be simpler and *maybe* it will produce a better explain plan. Something along these lines.

```
select
        cola,colb,colc
from t_master m
where not exists (
      select  null from a where m.keycol = a.fk_to_m
      )
and not exists (
      select  null from b where m.keycol = b.fk_to_m
      )
and not exists (
      select  null from c where m.keycol = c.fk_to_m
      )
union all
    select 
        cola,colb,colc from a
    where not exists (
          select  null from t_master m where a.fk_to_m = m.keycol
          )
union all
    select 
        cola,colb,colc from b
    where not exists (
          select  null from t_master m where b.fk_to_m = m.keycol
          )
union all
    select 
        cola,colb,colc from c
    where not exists (
          select  null from t_master m where c.fk_to_m = m.keycol
          )
```

You could union the 13 a,b,c ... tables to simplify the coding, but that may not perform so well.

Comment: I think i will go with your idea of using UNION ALL, meaning comparing the t_master with table a UNION ALL t_master with table b ....
however, I am stuck to get the XOR condition. I have updated the question with more info, hopefully i explained well with what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. I proposed in the first part of my suggestion should do all the comparisons needed from master to the 13 other tables THEN, for each of the 13 tables do the reverse one by one. How is there any remaining XOR? I also tried to steer you away from unioning a + b + c + ... as a first step. However I don't know how large your tables are etc. so I'm really guessing a great deal

Comment: hmm.ok.. i think i didn't fully understand your initial suggested solution. Now I just tried to implement it, but how can i get col from table a from the first 6 lines of your example code? Since a is residing in the 'NOT EXISTS' clause. I'm getting an invalid identifier error

Comment: If you need columns from within the table of a not exists subquery, then you have to use some other approach. This is where using real table names and real column names are needed. It isn't possible from the question to guess which columns you need or where they come from.

Comment: I've added on the sample code, let me know if you need more information?